# Can't connect to Google Cloud SQL instance from local machine

Tags: terminal, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to a production Google Cloud SQL instance from my local machine.

- I've whitelisted my IPv4 in the Allowed Networks section.
- I'm trying to connect to the database through it's IPv4 too.
- My password is definitely correct.
- I'm connecting *without* SSL.
- I'm using
  the following mysql command from the terminal:

  mysql --host=[INSTANCE_IP] --user=root --password

However, when I run the command I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Configuration steps for your use case listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP). Have you tried to connect to your instance using the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell)?

Answer (score 0):

The ERROR 1045 is a MySQL error, so the problem is not with establishing a connecting.

Are you 100% positive that your password is correct? You can use the Cloud Console to change your password and verify it is indeed what you think it is.